# reproject raster (WGS84 to BNG) with large resolution

Tags: r, coordinates, raster, proj

i'm doing a simple enough operation, reprojecting a raster from WGS84 to British National Grid, but i am wondering about some of the results post reprojection. The sum of the resulting rasters are quite different; is this due to the resolution and the way the bilinear interpolation in 'projectRaster' works?

I started with a csv that has global data covering the range of -180 to 180 degrees in both latitude and longitude (integer values only), with some z-values. this is subsetted, made into a raster of projection WGS84 and converted to BNG (subset below):

```
x <- rep(c(-10:3), times = 10)
n <- 14
y <- rep(48:57, each=n)
z <- rnorm(n=140, mean=20, sd=5)
ind <- which(z %in% sample(z, 45))
z[ind]<-NA
df <- data.frame("x"=x,"y"=y,"value"=z)

bng <- '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs'
wgs84 <- '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'

coordinates(df) = ~x + y
ras = rasterFromXYZ(df, crs=wgs84)
cellStats(ras,sum)
plot(ras)

ras_bng <- projectRaster(ras,crs=bng)
plot(ras_bng)
cellStats(ras_bng,sum)
```

the sum goes from 1919 to 2625 (in my case), a fair chunk.

Is it purely from the reprojection creating so many extra cells around the 'edges'? if i were to reproject to a raster of much smaller resolution (5km), would this reduce the differing sums considerably?

thanks, S

```
> ras
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 10, 14, 140  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : -10.5, 3.5, 47.5, 57.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 3.243918, 32.21532  (min, max)

> ras_bng
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 12, 19, 228  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 67900, 111000  (x, y)
extent      : -375677.8, 914422.2, -343553.2, 988446.8  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 8.174968, 28.31331  (min, max)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `NA` values in 'ras'.

The difference is small when you take out `z[ind]<-NA`. This is because `projectRaster` implicitly uses "na.rm=TRUE"; perhaps an argument is needed to change that. This is not as simple as in other cases, as, for example, only one of the cells interpolated from may be `NA`, in which case it should probably be computed.

In practice it is rare to find this many NA values, typically they are confined to the edges (of land) only.

By the way `WGS84` is a datum,it is not a projection. The projection you are using would be 'longitude/latitude' (also known by other names) except that this is also not a projection since the whole point of a projection is to go from such angular coordinates to planar coordinates. So, you are transforming one coordinate reference system ('long/lat, WGS84') to another (BNG).

Comment: thanks RobertH, yes a transformation, not a reprojection, bad wording. But i would still be using projectRaster in R? or perhaps proj4?

Comment: The function is still the same. Should perhaps be transformCrsRaster to be more specfic and general

Comment: also, as a note, changing the method in projectRaster to nearest neighbour retains the exact value. I am now stuck as to how to disaggregate this new raster to a 5km raster when the main raster is not 'divisible' by 5,000 and how the finer resolution raster will also add to the same as the raster it is disaggregating

Comment: Perhaps you can first disaggregate such that the cell sizes become similar. The same sum is not going to be possible if you get many more cells, the mean would perhaps be a better indicator?

Comment: it's odd, i've rasterized my csv wgs84 data and i just want the portion of that data that intersects a UK polygon. convert to BNG and disaggregate to 5km. with R, crop (near=out) is not what i need but mask is too stringent. i just want cells that simply touch the polygon!!

Comment: Could you transform the points data (use `spTransform`) and rasterize those to the 5 km grid?

Comment: actually i've done something that resembles your initial suggestion; in projectRaster, i nominated 'y' as an empty raster that holds the correct extent, crs and resolution. The new raster, transformed, is then masked by the UK and while it does not resolve all the issues, the resolution is finer so problems are reduced.

Comment: the main problem with what i have done above is that a 1 degree by 1 degree grid is not square (obviously) and is not exactly divisible by a 5km raster cell, therefore meaning the new resolution must have the values divided by a strange amount (approx 297.7). ah well.